# Do I know if Sending succeeds when it goes across planes?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

The [Sending](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sending) spell in 5e states:

> You can send the message across any distance and even to other planes of existence, but if the target is on a different plane than you, there is a 5 percent chance that the message doesn’t arrive.

Do I know if the spell actually goes across planes, or just if it fails?

Comment: Reminds me of the [Two Generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, the caster does not magically know if their message was received.

Since spells only do what they say, and *Sending* does not say that the caster knows if the message was properly received, the caster does not know. The text also alludes to it, saying "... there is a 5% chance that the message **doesn't arrive**." Not that it didn't send, or that the spell failed. You successfully *sent* the message, it just got lost. This is true whether or not you're on a different plane - you get no verification that it was received when you're on the same plane either, you just know that if it sent, it was received on this plane (Thanks, [@MivaScott](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/38834/mivascott)).

Obviously, since it doesn't say it explicitly, the DM can rule differently.

Also, keep in mind that the creature can respond. If the caster is expecting a response and doesn't receive one, they can at least assume *something* went wrong (although that doesn't necessarily mean the 5% chance happened, the creature could be dead or just didn't want to respond).

Comment: You might spell out that the spell never gives a "receipt", even if to a person across the room, so there would be no difference sending across planes.

Comment: +1 Bit pedantic, but even if it would say it explicitly the DM still could rule differently. And yes, I get that the idea was more like 'this is still vague enough that it's not entirely unlikely the DM might rule different', but still   .

Comment: @DaleM I'm not sure I agree with your edit, per this question: [Can Sending fail in either direction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112829/can-sending-fail-in-either-direction?rq=1)